# Rank.AVG function returning different results compared to SPSS

Tags: excel, statistics

I used Wilcoxon signed-rank test in SPSS and found it returns different sums of ranks compared to what RANK.AVG returns.

[image: Approach in Excel]

Excel gives me the sums 199.5 and 76. 5

In SPSS the sums of ranks (means too) are different.

[image: SPSS result]

I made sure the data is the same. Anyone has an explanation?

**EDIT**

As mentioned by Tom, the reason seems to be the rank column. RANK.AVG gives different ranks for the same numbers in my sheet. Google returns some results on this but nothing that helped me. For example, see the ranks for the 0.2 values below. But it also happens for other values. I started from scratch with a new Excel sheet, typing everything and not copying. But the problem persists.

| supporting | opposing | diff | abs diff | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.6 | 3.6 | 0 |  |  |
| 3.6 | 3.4 | 0.2 | ***0.2*** | ***4.5*** |
| 3.8 | 4.2 | -0.4 | 0.4 | 12 |
| 4.6 | 4.2 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 7 |
| 1.6 | 4.6 | -3 | 3 | 22 |
| 4 | 3.8 | 0.2 | ***0.2*** | ***4.5*** |
| 3.8 | 4.6 | -0.8 | 0.8 | 16.5 |
| 4.6 | 4.8 | -0.2 | ***0.2*** | ***4.5*** |
| 4.8 | 4.2 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 14 |
| 2.2 | 2.4 | -0.2 | ***0.2*** | ***2*** |
| 5 | 4.6 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 12 |
| 4.2 | 2.8 | 1.4 | 1.4 | 18 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 20 |
| 3.6 | 3.2 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 9 |
| 4.4 | 2.8 | 1.6 | 1.6 | 19 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 |  |  |
| 4.2 | 3.8 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 12 |
| 3.8 | 4.4 | -0.6 | 0.6 | 15 |
| 4.6 | 4.4 | 0.2 | ***0.2*** | ***1*** |
| 5 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 23 |
| 4.6 | 4.6 | 0 |  |  |
| 3.4 | 3 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 9 |
| 3.8 | 4 | -0.2 | ***0.2*** | ***4.5*** |
| 4 | 3.6 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 9 |
| 4 | 3.2 | 0.8 | 0.8 | 16.5 |
| 4.8 | 2 | 2.8 | 2.8 | 21 |

Comment: Did you check if any round options are set? My first suggestion is that you should reformat your excel and display two decimals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just checked and there is no rounding. From the second decimal onward it is always 0.

Comment: Maybe missing values are handled differently?

Comment: As I understood, there are 3 'missing' values that are neither in the negative nor the positive ranks column in Excel because the difference is zero. And these 3 should be the same as the 'ties' SPSS shows in the results. So I assumed Excel and SPSS exclude the same 3 values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something going wrong in the ranks column, e.g. 0.2 starts off with a rank of 4.5 and further down it has a rank of 1 - the same number can't have a different rank.

This is what I get for the ranks

[image]

The sums are reversed wrt to SPSS, but it would depend which way round you've entered the data.

---

[image]

The differences were due to rounding errors in the difference calculation. So put

```
=ROUND(Q5-R5,1)
```

when calculating the differences, and it's fine.

Comment: That's a good hint, I see it now too, thanks. Not sure what goes wrong though. What is your formula to calculate the ranks? I'm using =IF(D4=0,"",RANK.AVG(E4,$E$4:$E$29,1)), where D4 is the difference, E4 is the absolute difference, and E4 to E29 is the range of all absolute differences.

Comment: It's actually =IF(E4="","",RANK.AVG(E4,$E$4:$E$29,1)) but a blank in column E corresponds to a zero in column D, so it should be the same as yours.

Comment: Edited the question. Still not able to reproduce your results with the same formula and data. Any way you can share your Excel sheet with me?

Comment: Can you try this plz? https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtY3C2IFGCfCgZpuZHStqzdSvUOnXg?e=8Yzdgx

Comment: You may need this one - I renamed it 
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtY3C2IFGCfCgZpuZHStqzdSvUOnXg?e=Tep4Qh

Comment: Thanks, Tom. It works when I manually type the absolute differences. It does not work when I use RANK.AVG on the 'calculated' absolute differences (i.e. the cells with the formula). See the changes in your file. Good enough for me.

Comment: Aaargh, it's taken me a long time to realise this, but rather surprisingly it's rounding errors - see screenshot in my answer.